# mongoose findOne({email: email}) often works rarely doesn't work?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I use Mongoose 4.1.11

It's very very hard to perform this bug :

```
console.log("step1"); // that's display every time in my console => ok

models.users.findOne({email: mail}, function (err, myUser) {
    console.log("step2"); // That's very very weird, that's work but RARELY that's doesn't work
    ...
```

Sometimes, my API server doesn't work because of this problem,

**Edit #1**

so, I changed my server hosting from Gandi to Heroku. And now, its works very well ! Thank you for your help ;-)

Comment: This sounds more like a callback issue than a mongoose one. The code surrounding the `findOne()` is likely the culprit.

Comment: thank @cdbajorin but can you be more explicit, please ?
- for your information, look here : https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3504

Comment: I mean that the code that is the issue is in the `...` you have put in both this question and in your issue submission. The issue is likely the scope in which you have a callback executing, as I've written in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/cdbajorin/f2dfb6fc792503b8fbfa#file-endpoint-js)

Comment: so, I changed my server hosting from Gandi to Heroku. And now, its works very well !
Thank you for your help ;-)

Comment: I was facing the same issue but I fixed it with importing mongoose model. make sure to import a complete model for particular schema where you want to use "findOne".
in my case, I import the register model for login. now it works fine. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, I changed my server hosting from Gandi to Heroku. And now, its works very well ! Thank you for your help ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You should use **err** callback arguments, like below;

```
models.users.findOne({email: mail}, function (err, myUser) {
    if (!err) console.log("step2"); // That's very very weird,that's work but RARELY that's doesn't work
    else console.log(err.message);
    ...
```

Mongo generate error object when somethings went wrong and you can get error's reason in this usage.

Comment: Thank @furkan but I've got the same issue ;-)

Comment: can you share with me error message printed on console when issue happened?

Comment: thank you @furkan, look here for the console's printing ; https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3504

Comment: so, I changed my server hosting from Gandi to Heroku. And now, its works very well !
Thank you for your help ;-)

Comment: I glad to hear this @DonFabiolas

Answer (score 2):

```
    var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
    User.findOne({email: mail}, function (err, myUser) {
        console.log("step2"); // That's very very weird, that's work but RARELY that's doesn't work
    }
```

Comment: Thank @Alok, but I've got already created a schema, for your information:
var user = require('../schema/user');
exports.user = mongoose.model('user', user.schema);

Comment: use trim for email , may be there is any space

Comment: @DonFabiolas did you trim your email field

Comment: not yet @Alok, look my post here to see the console's printing : https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3504

Comment: thank again @alok
I just tested with : models.User2.findOne({email: "p9@gmail.com"}, function (err, userOne) {
but I've got the same issue.

Comment: @DonFabiolas any error you r getting in err parameter

Comment: Check with another query just find without any criteria

Comment: so, I changed my server hosting from Gandi to Heroku. And now, its works very well !
Thank you for your help ;-)

Comment: I would like but I cannot remove -1 sorry it's error of click mouse from me. I ask to stack overflow contact but my account, it's like banished ... very sorry ...